# How to solve airflow sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: operator?

Tags: ubuntu, airflow

I follow the steps in this [post](https://www.hackerxone.com/2021/10/15/steps-to-install-and-setup-apache-airflow-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) to install apache-airflow in Ubuntu 22.04 and try to start it.

```
(airflow_example) yashirq@yashirq:~/airflow_example/bin$ airflow db init
DB: sqlite:////home/yashirq/airflow/airflow.db
[2022-07-16 03:56:06,803] {db.py:1462} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, Add ``operator`` and ``queued_dttm`` to ``task_instance`` table
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: operator

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 38, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 51, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 35, in initdb
    db.initdb()
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 649, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1463, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, revision=to_revision or 'heads')
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 322, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 107, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 101, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 853, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 623, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/0004_1_5_0_more_logging_into_task_isntance.py", line 38, in upgrade
    op.add_column('task_instance', sa.Column('operator', sa.String(length=1000), nullable=True))
  File "<string>", line 8, in add_column
  File "<string>", line 3, in add_column
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 2047, in add_column
    return operations.invoke(op)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 399, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/operations/toimpl.py", line 154, in add_column
    operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 322, in add_column
    self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 195, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, multiparams)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1306, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 80, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1398, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/yashirq/airflow_example/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: operator
[SQL: ALTER TABLE task_instance ADD COLUMN operator VARCHAR(1000)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I found someone post a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72780519/sqlite3-operationalerror-duplicate-column-name-operator). But I don't quite get it. I don't know how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a more adequated way to solve this problem, but since you are just trying airflow deploy, and there's nothing that important to keep, what solved for me was the following:

```
airflow db reset
```

From what I got from this error, it's as if there is a duplicated entry for user etc, the line above solved for me.

To avoid this kind of issue, if you are just trying airflow, use:

```
airflow standalone
```

when initializing airflow.

Note: not a pro.

Comment: That's what I tried though it didn't help.